# Is it possible to run ExpressionEngine along side a Cake PHP site?

Tags: php, settings

I've been asked to add a CMS to an existing Cake PHP driven site. Cake PHP doesn't appear to drive much of the site outside of URL structure, templates and forms (there is no content management).

The client doesn't want to convert the entire site to ExpressionEngine all at once due to cost constraints.

I'm guessing CakePHP probably routes everything through index.php like EE does, so I'm wondering if it's possible to run them side by side?

I suppose on approach would be to run the ExpressionEngine portion on a sub domain. Are there any other approaches?

Thanks,

Anson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to installing EE on a subdomain, it's also perfectly possible to install it in a subdirectory rather than at web root.

You could just install it in a suitable directory with a name not used as a route in Cake, eg `/content/` etc.

This has the advantage of keeping your domain consistent for end users, with fairly minimal mucking about, though you may need a few `.htaccess` tweaks depending on if/how you are rewriting URLs to remove index.php.

Comment: Thanks Tom, that makes sense. When we port over the remaining content at a later time we'll just move the structure to the root folder.

Comment: Exactly, and with a quick rewrite all your EE URLs can continue to work. Glad I was able to help out anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Other than using a subdomain, you could rename index.php to something else, and use that as the router. That'd complicate cleaning up your URLs, certainly.

How big/complicated is the current site? Would it be easier to convert it all to EE than to try to work around integrating the two frameworks?

Comment: Thanks Dylan, some good points re complexity. Cost saving measures can often result in unexpected or more complex work else where. Not planning to integrate them much except for running the current site side by side with new EECMS functionality. Eventually it'll all be in EE.